# Dart. IDEA plugin. Tracing and output

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

When I run code with the `print` method in IDEA, the plugin just shows console command like 'path/dart.exe path/script.dart' and exit code. No output, no tracing of error/exception.
It worked fine earlier, but was broken from some time. Maybe after upgrading Dart SDK from 1.1.1 to 1.1.3. But why? Maybe I turned off some option in IDEA. I have no idea.
When I run same script in console it works well.
Here screen of this situation: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/452945

Upd. So, in the end, I made new project, and it works. Magic...

Comment: Hey, have you tried adding the checked option to your configuration just in case there might be something there? Although it seems to be coming from the ide I'd try it just in case.

Comment: I tried, but I didn't find any useful option. Dart plugin totally empty.